# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in public\...elementor\core\page-assets\data-managers\base.php on line 242

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, local, elementor

This error is occurring in the base.php file of the Elementor plugin at line 242. It seems to be related to trying to access an offset of a string that is treated as an array, but the value is actually a string.

Below is the function that throws error:

protected function get_saved_assets_data() {
$assets_data = get_option( self::ASSETS_DATA_KEY, [] );

```
    $content_type = $this->content_type;
    $assets_category = $this->assets_category;

    if ( ! isset( $assets_data[ $content_type ] ) ) {
        $assets_data[ $content_type ] = [];
    }

    if ( ! isset( $assets_data[ $content_type ][ $assets_category ] ) ) {
        $assets_data[ $content_type ][ $assets_category ] = [];
    }
    return $assets_data;
}
```

[Error trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1TA.png)

I tried all non-code methods to fix. Live link option on local cause the issue.